# Connection Refused - Ruby on Rails App Deployed using Capistrano, Nginx, and Puma on Linode Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, linode

I am using Linode to deploy a rails application. I have been following this tutorial: https://matthewhoelter.com/2020/11/10/deploying-ruby-on-rails-for-ubuntu-2004.html

When I try to access my site I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

I've been having trouble debugging this.

**nginx.conf**

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///home/deploy/apps/PhotographerFind/shared/tmp/sockets/PhotographerFind-puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server deferred;

  # If you're planning on using SSL (which you should), you can also go ahead and fill out the following server_name variable:
  # server_name example.com;

  # Don't forget to update these, too
  root /home/deploy/apps/PhotographerFind/current/public;
  access_log /home/deploy/apps/PhotographerFind/current/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /home/deploy/apps/PhotographerFind/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

**deploy.rb**

```
# # config valid for current version and patch releases of Capistrano
# lock "~> 3.15.0"

# Change these
server 'ip.address.here', port: 22, roles: [:web, :app, :db], primary: true

set :repo_url,        'git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/gitrepo/myrepo/myrepo'
set :application,     'PhotographerFind'

# If using Digital Ocean's Ruby on Rails Marketplace framework, your username is 'rails'
set :user,            'deploy'
set :puma_threads,    [4, 16]
set :puma_workers,    0

# Don't change these unless you know what you're doing
set :pty,             true
set :use_sudo,        false
set :stage,           :production
set :deploy_via,      :remote_cache
set :deploy_to,       "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :puma_bind,       "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
set :puma_state,      "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_access_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.access.log"
set :puma_error_log,  "#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"
set :ssh_options,     { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) }
set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true  # Change to false when not using ActiveRecord
    
namespace :puma do
    desc 'Create Directories for Puma Pids and Socket'
    task :make_dirs do
      on roles(:app) do
        execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/sockets -p"
        execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/pids -p"
      end
    end
  
    before :start, :make_dirs
  end
  
  namespace :deploy do
    desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
    task :check_revision do
      on roles(:app) do
        unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
          puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
          puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
          exit
        end
      end
    end
  
    desc 'Initial Deploy'
    task :initial do
      on roles(:app) do
        before 'deploy:restart', 'puma:start'
        invoke 'deploy'
      end
    end
  
    desc 'Restart application'
    task :restart do
      on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
        invoke 'puma:restart'
      end
    end
  
    before :starting,     :check_revision
    after  :finishing,    :compile_assets
    after  :finishing,    :cleanup
  end
  
  set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push("config/master.key")
```

**puma.access.log**

```
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.6 (ruby 2.6.3-p62), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 4, max threads: 16
* Environment: production
* Daemonizing...
=== puma startup: 2021-02-18 06:23:44 +0000 ===
=== puma startup: 2021-02-18 06:26:53 +0000 ===
* Listening on unix:///home/deploy/apps/PhotographerFind/shared/tmp/sockets/PhotographerFind-puma.sock
```

**puma.error.log**

```
=== puma startup: 2021-02-18 06:23:44 +0000 ===
/home/deploy/apps/PhotographerFind/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/binder.rb:395:in `for_fd': Bad file descriptor - fstat(2) (Errno::EBADF)
        from /home/deploy/apps/PhotographerFind/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/binder.rb:395:in `inherit_unix_listener'
        from /home/deploy/apps/PhotographerFind/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/binder.rb:115:in `block in parse'
        from /home/deploy/apps/PhotographerFind/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/binder.rb:90:in `each'
        from /home/deploy/apps/PhotographerFind/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/binder.rb:90:in `parse'
        from /home/deploy/apps/PhotographerFind/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/runner.rb:153:in `load_and_bind'
        from /home/deploy/apps/PhotographerFind/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/single.rb:98:in `run'
        from /home/deploy/apps/PhotographerFind/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/launcher.rb:186:in `run'
        from /home/deploy/apps/PhotographerFind/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/cli.rb:80:in `run'
        from /home/deploy/apps/PhotographerFind/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.6/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/deploy/apps/PhotographerFind/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/puma:23:in `load'
        from /home/deploy/apps/PhotographerFind/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/puma:23:in `<main>'
        from /home/deploy/apps/PhotographerFind/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
        from /home/deploy/apps/PhotographerFind/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
=== puma startup: 2021-02-18 06:26:53 +0000 ===
```

I think this may be pointing to the issue but it doesn't seem like it's every time puma starts so I'm not quite sure what's going on here.

---

**UPDATES**

I thought it may be port related, but this is the output of `sudo netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN`

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7307/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      963/sshd            
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      955/postgres        
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9200          :::*                    LISTEN      3892/java           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:9200                :::*                    LISTEN      3892/java           
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9300          :::*                    LISTEN      3892/java           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:9300                :::*                    LISTEN      3892/java           
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      963/sshd            
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      955/postgres
```

This is the content in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`:

```
2021/02/18 23:09:58 [notice] 7325#7325: signal process started
```

I've noticed that Puma only throws the Bad File descriptor on restart.  It appears to be running. This is the content of `puma.access.log`:

```
=== puma startup: 2021-02-18 23:04:28 +0000 ===
[6971] - Worker 0 (pid: 6973) booted, phase: 0
[6971] - Worker 1 (pid: 6979) booted, phase: 0
```

I thought that it may be a port problem, and get this output from `sudo ufw status numbered` which seems correct:

```
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 80,443/tcp                 ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 2] 22,80,443/tcp              ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 3] 80,443/tcp (v6)            ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[ 4] 22,80,443/tcp (v6)         ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

At this point I don't know where else to look for the root problem. Any suggestions?

**EDIT #2**
I have now noticed that if I try to go to the IP address in the browser I get the Connection Refused, but if I try to go IPADDRESS:3000 I get Connection Timed Out. I'm not sure if this is relevant.

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question but I followed the Ruby Yagi deployment tutorial on Linode with very few issues. Although looking closer, I see you're using Puma whereas this tutorial uses Passenger... https://rubyyagi.com/rails-deploy-automate-ansible

Comment: @Matthew Did you have to do any firewall configuration?

Comment: Nope, didn't need to do anything with the firewall myself (and I don't think the Ansible script did either - https://github.com/cupnoodle/rails-ansible). Regarding your edit, you shouldn't be going to IPADDRESS:3000, that's just for development... there's (probably) nothing listening on port 3000 in production, hence why you get a timeout with that

Comment: @Matthew Yeah I was using this to test just to see if I could get to anything.  `RAILS_ENV=production rails server --binding=server_public_IP`

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to your socket file, as per in your puma.error.log:

```
/home/deploy/apps/PhotographerFind/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/binder.rb:395:in `for_fd': Bad file descriptor - fstat(2) (Errno::EBADF)
```

You can try the following, only to confirm there is an issue with the socket file:

- Start puma in single worker mode with `-w 1`
- Use a port instead of a socket for thencommunication between nginx and puma

Both should work if I am not mistaking.

Your solution is to start puma as a service instead of starting it with Capistrano. To do so, you can follow puma's developers' documentation right here: https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/docs/systemd.md.

But, IMO you better use another application server, such as Passenger, for which you don't need a reverse proxy.

Comment: I have managed to get past the `Bad File Descriptor` error and puma has been running successfully from capistrano.  Why would running puma locally as a single worker make a difference?

Comment: @SaraTibbetts It seems to be an issue, perhaps because of access rights: https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/177